# Is there a way for cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to start at the bottom element with out scrolling?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want for the scroll to start at the bottom when I load my website but I don't want to use `this.viewPort.scrollToIndex` because then the user would see the scroll animation.  I was wondering if there is a way to achieve what I want or if I can use something other than `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`

Comment: If you sort your data in a specific way you might not need to start the list from the bottom?

Comment: I want to create a chat messenger, so i want the last message to be at the bottom, and I don't want the user to have to scroll down every time they wan to check their messages.